# Uncaught exception undefined within promise

Tags: javascript

I have trouble correcting an error in my script, the console simply states "uncaught exception: undefined". Could you help me to identify the source of the problem ?

General explanation: I am coding a "copy to clipboard" share-button for a web-app. When the button is pressed, a link get generated and copied to the user clipboard. The link generation is dependent on external factors, reports that are stored in an Oracle database. There is an array named **Reports** that keeps track of them, but it needs to be up to date to generate a functional sharing-link. The anonymous function **getterReports** does it in an asynchronous way (JQuery + AJAX).
In order to copy my data to the clipboard, I am using the method described in this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText

A snackbar (share_bar) is displayed on the screen to indicate that the operation is over.

Here is the raw code:

```
function copySharingURLToClipboard() {
    let share_bar = document.getElementById("modal_share");

    //getterReports ensures that the "Reports" array of reports objects is properly updated beforehand (AJAX <-> Database)
    getterReports().then(function () { //this ".then" ensurea that the main code is only executed after getterReports is over
        let report = getSavedReport(); //finds a report object by iterating the "Reports" array 

        if (report == undefined) { //no saved report were found
            //snackbar related code :
            document.getElementById("popup_message").innerHTML = "Temporary reports cannot be shared: please save your report first.";
            share_bar.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            share_bar.classList.add('show');//launching the fade-in fade-out animation from the associated css class
            setTimeout(function () { share_bar.classList.remove('show'); }, 4200);//removing the class after the animation is done
        }
        else {
            let data = BaseURL + "/DisplayReportPage.aspx?id=" + report.id; //generating the string that we want to copy in the clipboard
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(data).then(function () {
                /* success */
                //snackbar related code :
                document.getElementById("popup_message").innerHTML = "URL copied to the clipboard successfully";
                share_bar.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
                share_bar.classList.add('show');//launching the fade-in fade-out animation from the associated css class
                setTimeout(function () { share_bar.classList.remove("show"); }, 4200); //removing the class after the animation (it takes 4s + eventual minor latency)
            }, function () {
                /* failure case */
            });
        }
    });
}
```

During the execution of copySharingURLToClipboard(), the "uncaught exception: undefined" error happens in the following line, at ".then":

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText(data).then(function () {
```

My Web-app doesn't crash though, but the code is simply skipped. The error is only displayed when going step by step in devtool (otherwise the portion of the code is simply skipped without any error message). My Firefox browser is up to date.

All involved function are working fine in other part of the code. I am confident in the fact that getterReports() is working fine on its own. The same is true for the copy to clipboard part of copySharingURLToClipboard(), without the getterReports() updating the "Reports" array, it works fine (but its results are not up to date obviously):

```
function copySharingURLToClipboard() {
    let share_bar = document.getElementById("modal_share");

    //getterReports ensures that the "Reports" array is properly updated beforehand (AJAX <-> Database)
        let report = getSavedReport(); //finds a report object by iterating the "Reports" array 

        if (report == undefined) { //no saved report were found
            //snackbar related code :
            document.getElementById("popup_message").innerHTML = "Temporary reports cannot be shared: please save your report first.";
            share_bar.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            share_bar.classList.add('show');//launching the fade-in fade-out animation from the associated css class
            setTimeout(function () { share_bar.classList.remove('show'); }, 4200);//removing the class after the animation is done
        }
        else {
            let data = BaseURL + "/DisplayReportPage.aspx?id=" + report.id; //generating the string that we want to copy in the clipboard
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(data).then(function () {
                /* success */
                //snackbar related code :
                document.getElementById("popup_message").innerHTML = "URL copied to the clipboard successfully";
                share_bar.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
                share_bar.classList.add('show');//launching the fade-in fade-out animation from the associated css class
                setTimeout(function () { share_bar.classList.remove("show"); }, 4200); //removing the class after the animation (it takes 4s + eventual minor latency)
            }, function () {
                /* failure case */
            });
        }
}
```

Am I missing something simple ? A syntax error maybe ?

Comment: Hello! Can you try to add the failure case not as a secondary function, but by chaining a .catch(function() {})? If you used a then, you might as well stick with then&catch. If you want to use callbacks, use just callbacks. :)

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the .catch() usage, I will investigate it. Note that my script logic doesn't rely on catching errors (if it is similar to try...catch).

Also, what is the issue with having a .then inside another .then ? I am using this in other part of my project without facing any uncaught exception...

Comment: The issue is just that using only `.then()` defeats a primary purpose of using Promises, which is to escape callbacks and avoid sinking indent level after indent level. Your code would be much simpler, more readable and not creeping to the right as much if you were to use `async/await`, however it's likely not causing your error

Comment: @Klaycon I didn't know about async/await, it looks like my code can be greatly improved indeed. I will try to use it to simplify my code.

Comment: I think it might be a limitation of the navigator.clipboard.writeText(data) library. It returns an unresolved error in every situation where but the simplified script I posted. It may not be able to handle an asynchronous logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firefox does not allow async copy-to-clipboard functionality.**

Calling navigator.clipboard.writeText() in a promise resolve or an async function does not work intentionally. The code is working properly on other browsers.

After some research, it appears that there is still no available alternative implementation on Firefox. The logic of the project as a whole needs to be adapted in order to not use asynchronous functions when copying something in the clipboard.